# Регулярка в .gitlab-ci.yml artifacts path

Tags: регулярные-выражения, gitlab

Вроде как в `.gitlab-ci.yml` можно работать с регулярками - `RE2 google`. (Возможно я не прав, и вопрос уже тогда и закрыт).

Что я хочу: допустим у меня создается файл login_login.html. Чтобы он попал в артефакты делаем просто :

```
 artifacts:
    paths:
      - login_login.html
    expire_in: 3 days
```

Но вот я хочу забирать этот файл, но через регулярку - допустим по дате, но не суть важно.

Такая конструкция у меня не работает.

```
 artifacts:
    paths:
      - \w{1,10}_\w{1,10}\.html
    expire_in: 3 days
```

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать что я делаю не так, и как надо?

Comment: `- /\w{1,10}_\w{1,10}\.html/` а так?

Comment: @gil9red, так не работает, но вот `login_*.html` работает.
Но проблема что вот эта звездочка она видимо может работать только в конце файла и такого формата строку уже не видит `login_login_login.html`

Comment: @gil9red, ответил на свой вопрос.

Comment: Только там у вас не регулярка, а wildcard. Возможно, для `paths` регулярки нельзя использовать

Comment: @gil9red, не разбираюсь, но вроде получается так. 
Энивей можно тянуть хотя бы примерно похожие запросы.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем все оказывается просто. Методам проб и ошибок пришел к выводу , что знак * это любое кол-во ЛЮБЫХ символов.

Примеры :

```
artifacts:
    paths:
      - report_*.html
      - Tests/Screenshots/test_loginGood--*.png
      - Tests/Screenshots/test_loginBad--*.png
      - Tests/Screenshots/test_loginGood--*-*-*-*-*-*.png
      - Tests/Screenshots/test_loginBad--*-*-*-*-*-*.png
      - Tests/Screenshots/test_*.png
      - Screenshots/test_*.png
    expire_in: 3 days
```